# Upload data to aws s3 using curl in c++

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl

I'm trying to upload the data to aws s3 using following script and getting below error.

[image]

**Example Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
file_to_upload="/home/sraj/Hello10.txt"
bucket="mybucket"
filepath="/${bucket}/${file_to_upload}"
contentType='application\/x-compressed-tar'
dateValue="`date +'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`" 
signature_string="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${filepath}"
s3_access_key=xxxxxxxxx
s3_secret_key=yyyyyyyyy
signature_hash=`echo -en ${signature_string} | openssl sha256 -hmac ${s3_secret_key} -binary | base64`
echo "${s3_access_key} : ${s3_secret_key} : ${signature_hash}"
curl -X PUT -T "${file_to_upload}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3_access_key}:${signature_hash}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file_to_upload}
```

I think this is related to I AM user KMS encryption option.
Kindly help me how to solve above issue. I'm not much idea about curl and s3 also.
It will very helpful for sample code.

Some of them mentioned this is related to Signature version4 issue but I don't have much idea about fix this one.

Comment: Have you reviewed the instructions for [sigv4 signing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) vs sigv2?

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Answer (score 0):

The error says Invalid Argument.
I found this link, I have no idea if it will help.

[https://www.gyanblog.com/aws/how-upload-aws-s3-curl/#curl-the-savior`](https://www.gyanblog.com/aws/how-upload-aws-s3-curl/#curl-the-savior%60)

The only difference I see is the `dateValue`.  
I do not know if that matters, but just in case, I posted this.

```
# about the file
file_to_upload=<file you want to upload>
bucket=<your s3 bucket name>
filepath="/${bucket}/${file_to_upload}"

# metadata
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
signature_string="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${filepath}"

#s3 keys
s3_access_key=<your s3 access key>
s3_secret_key=<your s3 secret key>

#prepare signature hash to be sent in Authorization header
signature_hash=`echo -en ${signature_string} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3_secret_key} -binary | base64`

# actual curl command to do PUT operation on s3
curl -X PUT -T "${file_to_upload}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3_access_key}:${signature_hash}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file_to_upload}
```

Comment: That's still the v2 of the signing process.  v4 is required for KMS encryption

Comment: Hi @Anon Coward Please could you give idea about KMS encryption for V4. I have googled and tried its not working..Kinly help me..Sample example is very helpful..